# Unexpected behavior in a postgres group by query

Tags: postgresql

I am used to writing group by queries in t-sql. In a t-sql `group by`, this would generate a list where items with the same categorytext were grouped together, then items within a category text group that had the same type text would be grouped together. But that does not seem to be what is happening here:

```
Select   "CategoryText", "TypeText"
from "NewOrleans911Categories"
group by "CategoryText", "TypeText";
```

Here is some output from postgres. Why are the NAs not getting grouped together?

```
    CategoryText; TypeText
    "BrokenWindows";"DRUG VIOLATIONS"
    "NA";"BOMB SCARE"
    "Weapon";"DISCHARGING FIREARMS"
    "NA";"NEGLIGENT INJURY"
```

Comment: This query will work the same in t-sql. What TypeText do you expect to see in the grouped record with CategoryText = 'NA'?

Comment: Are you confusing `GROUP BY` with `ORDER BY` somehow? `GROUP BY` returns *one row* for each distinct combination; `ORDER BY` would retain all rows, but ones that were identical would be next to each other in the results. Combinations of both clause are also possible (and in most cases you definitely want an `ORDER BY` clause of some sort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In a t-sql group by, this would generate a list where items with the same categorytext were grouped together, then items within a category text group that had the same type text would be grouped together.

In SQL, the order in which rows are returned by a query is unspecified, unless you toss in an order by clause. Typically, you'll get the rows in the order they got returned by the query, and that would entirely depend on the query plan. (Best I'm aware, t-sql does that too.)

At any rate, you'd want to add the missing order by clause to get the expected result:

```
Select   "CategoryText", "TypeText"
from "NewOrleans911Categories"
group by "CategoryText", "TypeText"
order by "CategoryText", "TypeText";
```

Or (and I suspect this is what you're actually looking for) replace the group by with an order by clause:

```
Select   "CategoryText", "TypeText"
from "NewOrleans911Categories"
order by "CategoryText", "TypeText";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are "grouping" by two columns. The rows are only "Grouped " when the records match both columns.

In that case you have different TypeText for both NA, so they will not group by. Much like using a distinct, which in that case will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: How do I select everything from the table but group them by only "CategoryText"? If I do select * from NewOrleans911Categories group by "CategoryText" then I get ERROR:  column "NewOrleans911Categories.TypeText" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do there. Can you be a little more clear on what are the expected results ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need query like this:

```
select distinct on ("CategoryText") "CategoryText", "TypeText"
from "NewOrleans911Categories"
```

because with `group by` you cannot select columns which aren't in `group by` statement.

Comment: `Distinct On` is only meaningful with an `Order By` clause to tell Postgres what the "first" value for the non-distinct columns is.